# Making the `nosetests` script select folder by Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I used to have this in my `setup.cfg` file:

```
[nosetests]
where=test_python_toolbox
```

But now I'm supporting Python 2 and Python 3 by supplying two parallel codebases, one in the `source_py2` folder and one in the `source_py3` folder. `setup.py` knows how to check the Python version and choose the correct one. Problem is, I don't know how to make `nosetests`, when invoked in the repo root, select the correct folder.

I could have this:

```
[nosetests]
where=source_py2/test_python_toolbox
```

But then tests would work only for Python 2. I want them to work for both versions.

I could launch `nosetests` with a flag, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[nosetests]
where=source_py2/test_python_toolbox
py3where=source_py3/test_python_toolbox
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `where` which is deprecated,  use `tests` and specify multiple tests:

```
[nosetests]
tests=source_py2/test_python_toolbox, source_py3/test_python_toolbox
```

This will run both set of tests. For each test, at the very top, before language specific features are in place, add the selection criteria for running tests. For example, for `source_py3` tests add:

```
import sys
from unittest import SkipTest

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    raise SkipTest("must use python 3.0 or greater")
```

With python2.6 nose you will get:

```
S
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

for each test module that has it. The ugly aspect is that you have to inject this code in every test case.

Comment: Wouldn't this make Wing try to run tests in both folders, thus getting many exceptions when trying to run tests for Python 2 on Python 3?

Comment: May be you want two config files in this case? You can also decorate your tests and provide selection based on attributes if you do not want exceptions, but in reality you are probably using different nosetests binaries for two versions, so I would see no issue with two config files.

Comment: Or add a skipIf decorator and condition it on something, i.e:          `@unittest.skipIf(mylib.__version__ < (1, 3),
                     "not supported in this library version")`

Comment: Having two config files would require running a flag with `nosetests`, no? I prefer to put as little requirements as possible for the person running  `nosetests`. Regarding putting selection logic in the tests themselves: I considered that, but then realized that some Python 3 files wouldn't even be able to compile under Python 2, so they'd raise a `SyntaxError` before the selection logic could even kick in.

Comment: May be place one config files in source_py2 and one in source_py3, and specify which one is used with `-c` command line? In any case you have to have some place for selection logic. It is largely up to you to figure out which tests to run ;-)

Comment: Of course I need to put the selection logic someplace, I'm just looking for a place that doesn't involve making the user use a flag, but rather by detecting the Python version used.

Comment: Your edit is not helpful because some files will result in `SyntaxError` and won't even compile.

Comment: You should try it. The module will be skipped on import, even with obvious syntax errors after the statement.

Answer (score 1):

[tox](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html) can do that via multiple environment specifications, and the `changedir` option (just override that per Python version).

Comment: I'd prefer to keep using nose rather than switching to a different test runner.

Comment: Then you need to write a nose plugin, based on "--where".

Comment: Okay, that's an option. But, would any person who wants to run my test have to install my plugin? Or can it be included with the repo and used automatically when a user runs `nosetests` with no arguments at the repo root? (Assuming that user doesn't have my plugin installed.)