# Using nose to test mixed python2 and python3 code

Tags: python, nose

I have a project that has both python2 and python3 code in it (its a client/server thing; the server is python3 but there are python2 and python3 clients). I'm using nose to handle unit testing. The directory layout is (currently) basically like

```
client2
    tests
client3
    tests
server
    tests
```

Is there a way to set up or use nose so that running node with python2 gets just the python2 tests, and similarly python3. For instance, something like:

```
client2
    tests2
client3
    tests3
server
    tests3
```

... with some suitable nose arguments. I messed around with the -m option but couldn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need a combo of `--where` and `--py3where`:

> --py3where:
>
> Look for tests in this directory under Python 3.x. Functions the same
>   as 'where', but only applies if running under Python 3.x or above. 
>   Note that, if present under 3.x, this option completely replaces any
>   directories specified with 'where', so the 'where' option becomes
>   ineffective. [NOSE_PY3WHERE]

So for you it would be something like this:

```
nosetests --where=. --where=client2 --py3where=. --py3where=client3 --py3where=server -v
```

When using nosetests with python3 it will run `client3` and `server` tests only. When running on python2 it will run `client2` tests only.

Also, have a look at [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804563/making-the-nosetests-script-select-folder-by-python-version/18838520#18838520) for alternatives.